# How to retrieve text content from EACH select element options and distribute dynamically to div > span elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to gather the option text values from each select element on a page dynamically and distribute each group of select element text values to their own div, and the text values be placed within span tags that are appended to each div. I hope that makes sense...

I'm currently attempting to do this with an object and some methods. I have tried a constructor function alike and ran into the same issues.

The output I'm receiving after the second loop is the length of the select element with the most options in it, and it isn't distributing the text values accurately to separate divs.

Here is the code I am using so far:

```
(function(window, document, $) {

$(document).ready(function() {

    select.css("display","none");

    var select = $("select"),
        selectArr = $(select).toArray(),
        a = b = c = 0;      

var selecto = {}
selecto.div = $("<div/>");
selecto.div.addClass("select-box");
selecto.replaceSelect = function() {
    $(selecto.div).insertBefore(select);
}
selecto.replaceSelect();
selecto.getOptions = function() {
    for (; a < selectArr.length; a += 1) {
        for (; b < selectArr[a].length; b += 1) {
            $("<span>" + $(selectArr[a][b]).text() + "</span>").appendTo(".select-box");
        }
    }
}
selecto.getOptions();

    });

})(window, document, jQuery);
```

I'm going to attempt using a function expression next, as the object doesn't seem to work too well since it is only referencing selecto.div and not making copies, which in turn always results in selecto.div.length = 1.

What I would like to happen would be taking the following:

```
<select>
    <option>option 1</option>
    <option>option 2</option>
</select>

<select>
    <option>option A</option>
    <option>option B</option>
    <option>option C</option>
    <option>option D</option>
</select>
```

and turning it into this, dynamically:

```
<div class="select-box">
    <span>option 1</span>
    <span>option 2</span>
</div>

<div class="select-box">
    <span>option A</span>
    <span>option B</span>
    <span>option C</span>
    <span>option D</span>
</div>
```

Is it a problem with my loop statements? Maybe the object itself? Or is it because JavaScript is having a tough time working with a JAGGED array?

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('select').each(function () {
        $select = $(this);
        $div = $('<div>');
        $div.addClass('select-box');
        $select.find('option').each(function () {
            $div.append($('<span>').text(this.innerText));
        });
        $select.replaceWith($div);
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/07p6ydz7/1/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Is there a simple way to do this without using jQuery (I love jQuery, but seeing it from both angles would give me a stronger understanding of what's happening on the whole side of things). Or even what I was doing wrong with my formula?

Comment: you can do this with DOM manipulation, but it's anything but simple. Basically you'd iterate over `document.getElementsByTagName('select')` and then iterate over each option in each select, extracting their innerText and finally replacing the div with the select element by traversing the dom tree and performing a replace in the elements position. http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom2.shtml illustrates the concept

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I truly would like to become masterful with JS at some point, so any information helps.

For fun, and to gain experience I've built a simple validation script with jQuery: http://heresjonny.ca/dev/validation-spread/js/validate.js and you can see the result here: http://heresjonny.ca/dev/validation-spread/

If you could take a look at my code, I'd appreciate any constructive criticism you could throw at me. Possibly relating to my developing pattern, use of methods, etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyhow, this is what came out of it: http://heresjonny.ca/dev/select-box/ so far..